# Insert into table linked by foreign key

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've got 2 tables:

**TravelRequest**

```
TravelReqID(PK)
PlanningTypeCode(FK)
Days
Hours
Mail
```

**PlanningType**

```
PlanningTypeCode(PK)
PlanningType
```

I want to insert some records into `TravelRequest` but I need to show also `PlanningType.PlanningType`.

I tried this query

```
INSERT INTO [Travel].[TravelRequest]([PlanningType].PlanningType,Days,Hours,Mail)
VALUES('Start Training',10,1,1)
```

But SQL Server shows me this error:

> Invalid column name 'PlanningType'.

How can I insert PlanningType value?

Comment: You get the error because your [Travel].[TravelRequest] table doesn't have PlanningType column, this column exists in PlanningType table so you need a separate insert for that.

Comment: Please expand column names in each table and show us , so we could give u better solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your `INSERT` statement is not correct.

Insert syntax is like following.

```
INSERT INTO table_name (column1, column2, column3, ...)
VALUES (value1, value2, value3, ...);
```

Where all the columns should be from the table where you are trying to insert the data.

You should be writing your query like following. [Assuming that `TravelReqID` is `Identity` column)

```
INSERT INTO TravelRequest(PlanningTypeCode,Days,Hours,Mail)
SELECT PT.PlanningTypeCode,10,1,1
FROM [PlanningType] PT
WHERE PT.PlanningType='Start Training'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write to two table without creating a link between the two in your query.
You need to create a join before you can write a query like that.

Comment: Ok, I did the join 
SELECT *
FROM [Travel].[TravelRequest]
LEFT JOIN [Planning].[PlanningType] on [TravelRequest].PlanningTypeCode=[PlanningType].PlanningTypeCode

I put the insert into instruction next the join but I've got the same error